# Extending the UITableView further Down

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I'm running into an issue which involves a table view and a keyboard. I have my program developed so that whens electing a table view, it scrolls the table view up past the keyboard, so that it can remain visible, by calculating the amount of scrolling up that is required to keep the text field visible, and then using a transform to move the frame that far up.

Since the UIView is still active, I can continue scrolling in the smaller view and select other text entries and make changes to them.

The problem occurs that I cannot see the bottom items in my list. I'd like to extend the "tolerance" for not scrolling to be equal to about the height of my keyboard, and then set it back to default after I dismiss my keyboard.

Thanks.

Comment: So what is your question? Seems to me like you have it all figured out.

Comment: My question is how to increase the scroll tolerance. If I have 600 pixels of content in my scroll view and a keyboard of a height 146, and I select something from the top of the view, and then scroll the window (with the keyboard still up), I cannot access any item in the last 146 pixels of content without first dismissing the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice way that might also look good is to not just scroll the tableView, but instead move the whole tableView (and maybe its surrounding view) up by the height of the keyboard (and, of course, down again upon dismissal).

```
myTableView.center = CGPointMake(myTableView.center.x, myTableView.center.y - keyboardHeight); //and vice versa for keyboard dismissal
```

If this works, you can experiment with animating it.

If you want to be able to scroll the tableView up further than ordinarily possible, you could try setting its `contentSize` property prior to scrolling. Since `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, this should work if Apple didn't somehow override its behavior.

```
myTableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(myTableView.contentSize.width, myTableView.contentSize.height + keyboardHeight); //and vice versa when keyboard is dismissed
```

Comment: This worked for me, although, the View I was being given was a standard View, so I had to iterate through the subviews to find a scroll view that I could adjust the content size.

Comment: Be careful, though - Apple doesn't like us poking around in its classes like that. I just remembered a way that requires no enumeration of subviews: add a footer view to the table with the required size.

Answer (score 1):

why modify the frame of the table? you could just use the  `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` on UITableView and then you wouldn't have worry about modifying the frame of the tableview when the keyboard appeared and disappeared

Comment: From what I can gather, the standard way of doing it is to calculate the required distance to move and move the bottom of the frame by that much. The delegate being used is also used for other areas then just the scrollview when this can happen, so we wanted to keep it consistent.

Also, scrollToRow may not work in some cases where the iPhone keyboard appears for numbers, where we use a ToolBar overlay with a "Done" button to dismiss the number keypad.